# Give a role when a user responds with a custom emoji (Discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

**Below is the currently working code for my case**

I'm working on a bot for my Discord server and trying to assign a role to a user with a reaction.

My current status looks like this: (I used the latest Python/Discord.py version)

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(intents=intents)


class GetRole(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot 
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reacion_add(payload):
   ourMessageID = YourMessageID

   if ourMessageID == payload.message_id:
       member = payload.member
       guild = member.guild

            
      if payload.emoji.name == '<:YouTube:864980517630902302>':
          role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="YouTube")
      elif payload.emoji.name == '<:Twitch:864980843176787988>':
          role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Twitch")
      elif payload.emoji.name == '<:Discord:864980938068852757>':
          role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Discord")
      elif payload.emoji.name == '<a:alert:864983948987990081>':
          role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Community-Events")
      await member.add_roles(role)
```

(the message meant by the MessageID has already been sent)
It does not produce errors in Visual Studio code, but the roles are still not added to the user who reacts to the message.

Maybe it is because of the versions of Discord.py, but I don't know exactly.

Comment: Did you make sure the code is indented correctly? Have you enabled intents?

Comment: Should I, yes 
->`intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.reactions = True`

Comment: @H.Philipp yes, on_raw_reaction_add requires the use of the members and reactions intents. Enable them like you said, and then when you define your bot make sure to include the `intents=intents` keyword argument. You will also need to enable them for your bot in the developer portal.

Comment: Thanks, I think i forgot to enable `intents=intents`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now the working code:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
        print("test")
        print(payload.emoji.name)

        ourMessageID = 867876893411508234

        if ourMessageID == payload.message_id:
            member = payload.member
            guild = member.guild
            

            if payload.emoji.name == 'YouTube':
                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="YouTube")

            elif payload.emoji.name == 'Twitch':
                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Twitch")

            elif payload.emoji.name == 'Discord':
                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Discord")

            elif payload.emoji.name == 'alert':
                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Community-Events")

            await member.add_roles(role)
```

I had typos and used (I think) outdated evets etc. Now everything works again at least for me

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the appropriate intents are enabled. As per the [Discord.py API Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_raw_reaction_add), both the members and reactions intents are required to use the `on_raw_reaction_add` event. Enable them in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications/), and add the intents in your code like so:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.reactions = True

bot = commands.Bot(intents=intents)
```

Comment: Thanks, I added it. The rest of my code is okay?

Comment: It all looks good to me, although I'm not super familiar with the emoji class so I don't know whether emoji.name returns the reference with brackets like that or just a name for the emoji. But if your if statements aren't triggering you can try printing the payload/the emoji name to see what is happening

Comment: When I try to add `bot = commands.Bot(intents=intents)` My IDE shows [this](https://i.imgur.com/I2tLOzm.png)
Do I need to import anything particular?